# XCTest waitForExpectations(...) waiting multiple results

Tags: ios, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

In UITest, after tapping the login button, I need to wait for two events, wether update or home screen is presented after login was successful and decide what to do.
The documentation says, that

> Only one -waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:handler: can be active at any given time, but
>        * multiple discrete sequences of { expectations -> wait } can be chained together.

So needed to work it around a bit, but finally figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can add arguments to the predicate and use OR between conditions.

```
let skipUpdateButtonPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@.exists == 1 OR %@.exists == 1", skipUpdateButton, homeTabBar)
self.expectation(for: skipUpdateButtonPredicate, evaluatedWith: [Any](), handler: nil)
testCase.waitForExpectations(timeout: Constants.loginTimeout,
                                 handler: nil)
```

Then you can branch here, if the home or update is presented:

```
if skipUpdateButton.exists {
    skipUpdateButton.tap()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using expectations, you can set the number of times it needs to be fulfilled.

```
let expectations = expectation(description: "AsyncExpectations")
expectations.expectedFulfillmentCount = 4


    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
    // do work here
    expectations.fulfill()
}


DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    // do work here
    expectations.fulfill()
}

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
    // do work here
    expectations.fulfill()
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // do work here
    expectations.fulfill()
}

// wait for all 4 expectations
waitForExpectations(timeout: 2, handler: nil)
```